# Waterfall plot GenVisR

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor

I'm using the function [waterfall from GenVisR package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GenVisR/inst/doc/waterfall_introduction.html). As the vignette suggests, I am changing the top plot with custom values. However, those values cannot be specified and appear in gray as "Undefined" (see image)

[image].

I would like to add a layer with ggplot in order to define (and colour) the barplot like the following plot:

[image]

In the vignette the authors have an argument called `mutBurdenLayer` that seems to do the job but I'm not able to change the graph.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
library(GenVisR)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
custom_pallete <- brewer.pal(8, "Paired")
waterfall(VCFs, coverageSpace = 179977, main_geneLabSize = 5,
          mainLabelSize = 2, mainLabelCol="HGVSp", mainDropMut = T,
          mainPalette = custom_pallete, mainXlabel = T)
```

I would like to add something like:

```
mut_burden_layer <- theme(...)
waterfall(VCFs, coverageSpace = 179977, main_geneLabSize = 5,
          mainLabelSize = 2, mainLabelCol="HGVSp", mainDropMut = T,
          mainPalette = custom_pallete, mutBurden = mut, mainXlabel = T,
          mutBurdenLayer = mut_burden_layer)
```

Being `mutBurden` a data table with the new proportions and `mutBurdenLayer` the parameter I would like to custom.

Comment: Hi @akrun! I didn't change any parameter here. I just used the same data for the main plot and the upper one and then the waterfall function perfroms the classfication correctly. However, sometimes I would like to customize this numbers and I would like to plot also the proportions.

Comment: Hi @akrun, I updated the post with an example code. Hope it clarifies the issue!

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(VCFs)`

Comment: Hi @Tung. The ouptut is kind of big, if you load the GenVisR package, they have a preload sample data (brcaMAF). Is this way maybe more informative?